# if statement to identify directory path

Tags: python

I've got watchdog and pyaudio playing together so if either of two directories is modified I hear a sound.

Now I'm trying to get a different sound for each directory. Watchdog can print the path that triggered it, so I'm trying to use that difference to fire each sound.

```
def on_modified(self, event,):
        x = event.src_path
        print(x)
        if x == 'c:/WATCHDOGTEST\x.csv':
            pyaudio_01.PLAY_SOUND()
        if x == 'c:/WATCHDOGTEST2\x.csv':
            pyaudio_02.PLAY_SOUND()
```

The print(x) works fine:

```
c:/WATCHDOGTEST2\x.csv
```

however - the if statement won't work - I get:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \xXX escape
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Try `if x == 'c:/WATCHDOGTEST\\x.csv':'` (double backslash).

Comment: More info here [How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/how-should-i-write-a-windows-path-in-a-python-string-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\x` in the string, python interprets anything after `\x` as hexadecimal charector, so you need to escape this charector, using one more slash.
So your value will be `c:/WATCHDOGTEST\\x.csv`

Or you can turn it into raw string using r formater, `r'c:/WATCHDOGTEST\x.csv'`, this is the best way, beacuse it automatically ignores any special charectory if present.

Answer (score 1):

OK just figured it out - I added a forward slash to the target directory to get rid of the backslash it added itself, now it works. Doh.

Answer (score 1):

- using built-in library pathlib would be more easy.

```
PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files/').match(event.src_path)
```

- [Pure path objects provide path-handling operations which don’t actually access a filesystem. There are three ways to access these classes, which we also call flavours.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)